# I need to overwrite CompareTo method in a subclass

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have a class A which implements Comparable interface, and a class B which extends A. I need to find a way to overwrite `compareTo` in class B.

I found a similar question 
[Cannot use comparable with father-son-grandson inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694848/cannot-use-comparable-with-father-son-grandson-inheritance/8694890)
And tried to implement offered solution

**Class A:**

```
public class A<E extends A> implements Comparable<E>{
    String surname;
    int age;
      A(String surname, int age){
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

   public  int compareTo(E o) {
        int res=0;
        res =this.surname.compareTo(o.surname);
        if(res==0)
            res = this.age-o.age;
        return res;
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public class B extends A<B> {
    int num;

    Student(String surname, int age, int num){
        super(surname,age);
        this.num = num;
    }
@Override
   public int compareTo(B o){
        int res=0;
        res =this.surname.compareTo(o.surname);
        if(res==0)
            res = this.age-o.age;
        if(res ==0){
            res= this.num-o.num;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class T4.A
>   cannot  be cast to class T4.B (T4.A and T4.B are in unnamed module of
>   loader 'app')

Comment: What code snippet do you get the classcastexception? This example works fine without such exception. Are you trying to cast like `B b = (A) a;

Comment: check [java.lang.ClassCastException
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511169/java-lang-classcastexception), your code seems to work fine for me too, its maybe the way you are calling the classes that is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the code which fails?

I just tried it on my own machine and it seems to work. The only time I could recreate the error was with following code: `b.compareTo((B) a);`
Which can't work since you can't cast a parent type to its child type.

Also, I think it is just a copy error, but you are missing brackets in the provided code and constructor of class B does not match the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Your method in class `B` should be written as this instead:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(B o){
    int res=0;
    res =this.surname.compareTo(o.surname);
    if(res==0)
        res = this.age-o.age;
    if(res ==0){
        res= this.num-o.num;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added @Override but it didn't help

Comment: @Connor Ruggles, This is not going to help. The annotation has nothing to do with overriding in Java. That method has already been overridden.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha It won't solve the problem, but of course the annotation has something to do with overriding :/

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think so. I was referring to the concept of override. It's a runtime operation and with or without an annotation, it stays the same. As long as method signature & return type are the same override works. So it doesn't. Of course, annotation provides compile time safety.

Comment: So it's related then. Saying it's "unrelated" is nonsense; it's *directly* related, as you stated. As i said, it's not *necessary*, but it's clearly related to overriding by definition.

Comment: Picking words without understanding the whole doesn’t help @DaveNewton.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha Which is why I take issue with saying the Override annotation doesn't have anything to do with overriding. Saying an annotation explicitly about overriding isn't related is wrong, because it's imprecise (and because it's *only* about overriding), even if it isn't *required* to override a method.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha ah my bad, I haven’t written java in a couple years and thought that was required for an override.

Answer (score 0):

Student != B

The class B need to have a contructor called B